# Run mvn package on docker file

Tags: spring, maven, docker, jar, dockerfile

I'm trying to generate the jar for a maven project before building the image using a docker file:

```
FROM maven:3.2-jdk-7-onbuild

RUN mkdir /api

COPY . /api

RUN mvn package -f /api/pom.xml

EXPOSE 9000
```

Is this even possible? What i'm trying to do is to create a jar to execute it later.

I'm getting this among others:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) on project deivapi: Execution default-jar of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
[ERROR]
```

Comment: did you not try running it?

Comment: I did, but I got so much errors...

Comment: Your question doesn't have any, please update the quesiton with proper details.

Comment: Why are you trying to build inside a Docker container? Building an application and copying the result into the Docker container makes sense?

Comment: So I don't have to be worriwd about the jar in git. This way the docker file would de enough

Comment: The issue is with your `pom.xml`, you have a plugin which is not compatible with the maven version. Please post complete pom.xml to your question